# Trying to filter by user group using class based view with django-tables2, can't access self.user

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-users, django-tables2

I'm trying to use a class based view using django-tables2 to define the table and template returned based on what group the logged in user belongs to.

This is my attempt at doing so:

```
class cases(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    login_url = '/account/login/'
    if User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id, groups__name='teachers').exists():
        model = Graduation
        table_class = TeachersTable
        template_name = 'mysite/teachers.html'
    elif User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id, groups__name='students').exists():
        model = Graduation
        table_class = StudentsTable
        template_name = 'mysite/students.html'
```

I *think* the approach is more or less correct (I've only learned about class based views today), but I am unsure how to access the user id.

The relevant parts of this view should only be called when a user is logged in (at least I think) because  I'm using the LoginRequiredMixin, so 'self' should exist.

The answers I have seen addressing this problem say override get_queryset, but I am reluctant to do that as I think that will break django-tables2.

What is the best approach in this case to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

First, all code in a class runs when the module is loaded, not when the view is run. So your code is running at the wrong time. Partially because of this, you don't have access to `self`.

`self` isn't that magic, it doesn't appear from nowhere, you can only use it in class methods:

```py
class Foo:
    self.spam = "eggs"  # Wrong, no self here.

class Bar:
    def set_spam(self):  # self is the instance of the class.
        self.spam = "eggs"  # Works.
```

I'm not sure what table_class is, from a search it looks like it comes from django-tables, so there's a bit of guesswork here. It seems like you want something like this:

```py
class GraduationCaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    model = Graduation
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name='teachers').exists():
            return ['mysite/teachers.html']
        return 'mysite/students.html'

    def get_table_class(self):
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name='teachers').exists():
            return TeachersTable
        return StudentsTable
```

This should work. There is an issue with this: you'd be doing the same database query twice. There are some ways around this, but it requires knowing a bit about CBVs and their execution order. Since I'm not sure what `SingleTableView` is doing, this may or may not work:

```
class GraduationCaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    model = Graduation
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name='teachers').exists():
            self.group = 'teachers'
        else:
            self.group = 'students'
        return qs
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.group == 'teachers':
            return ['mysite/teachers.html']
        return 'mysite/students.html'

    def get_table_class(self):
        if self.group == 'teachers':
            return TeachersTable
        return StudentsTable
```

You should probably read up on [Python's documentation of classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), too, so you understand how they work.

One more thing, you don't need to set `login_url` on your view if `settings.LOGIN_URL` is set.

Comment: Interesting, and thank you very much for your explanation. I'm going to take what you've said here and see how far I get. Out of curiosity, how would your answer change if I wanted to use a different model for teachers and students? That is the plan eventually, I was just focusing on having the group checking working first. I'm guessing another method would be made to return the model based on self.group?

Comment: At that point I would probably consider if two views would be better than one. However, it's not mandatory to set the `model`, you can instead use the `get_queryset()` method to return the queryset you want. You'd need to change the code a bit, as `get_object()` calls `get_queryset()`. So you'd need to override `get_queryset()`, add the query to get the group in there instead of `get_object()`, then return the queryset you want based on the group. I took a look at django-tables2's code and it's not overriding `get_queryset()` for anything, so it should work well.

Comment: The issue is I want it to be the same url for people in either group to go to. As far as I know that can't work with two different views? based on your answer here, why would it not work to use a method to set user id to a variable outside of that method but still belonging to the class. Then would my attempt in the question be possible?

Comment: Also I just tried your final view as is and get an error that GraduationCaseView object has no attribute 'group' - is there something specific that needs to be imported? I was importing 'User' from 'django.contrib.auth.models' and just imported 'Group' as well but it made no difference. -- I'm going to attempt using get_queryset and doing the group checking in there but was curious about the error.

Comment: It's possible that `get_table_class()` is called before `get_object()`. I would probably try overriding `get_queryset()` instead, I've updated the answer and fixed an error in there as well.

Comment: Views are just functions (or classes that act like functions) so you can just have a view that is a simple view that then delegates to one of the CBVs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get everything working as I wanted, your answer and explanations helped immensely.